# FluentValidation Validate object by id

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Using FluentValidation I typically pass Ids vs the objects in Commands.  Yet I want to validate that an object with the id exists, and then validate that object.

Is there a better way than the below method?

```
    public class ProjectIdValidator : AbstractValidator<int>
    {

        public ProjectIdValidator(MyDbContext aDbContext)
        {
            Custom(aProjectId =>
            {
                var project = aDbContext.Projects.Find(aProjectId);
                if (project == null)
                {
                    return new ValidationFailure("ProjectId", "Project does not exist");
                }
                var projectValidator = new ProjectValidator();
                var x = projectValidator.Validate(project);
                if (x.IsValid)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return new ValidationFailure("ProjectId", x.Errors.ToString());

            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I think this is a better way.

```
AddRule(new DelegateValidator<Command>((aCommand, aContext) =>
{
    // return an IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> from in here:
    var projectId = (int?) aCommand.ProjectId;
    if (projectId.HasValue)
    {

        using (var dbContextScope = aDbContextScopeFactory.CreateReadOnly())
        {
            MyDbContext dbContext = dbContextScope.DbContexts.Get<MyDbContext>();
            Project project = dbContext.Projects.Find(projectId);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return Enumerable.Repeat(new ValidationFailure("ProjectId", "ProjectId not found"),1);
            }

            var projectValidator = new ProjectValidator();
            var results = projectValidator.Validate(project);

            return results.Errors;
        }
    }
    return null;
}));
```

Comment: Do you really want a new `DbContext` instance for each validation rule? Wouldn't it be better to have a request-scoped `DbContext` that can be reused for all command validations (as well as the command db operations after validation passes)?

Comment: @Dan Yes that is a good point.  This is only sample code but  Get<MyDbContext> if already in a scope will reuse the existing context. http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/ has a nice blog about it.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
public class UpdateProjectCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<UpdateProjectCommand>
{
    public UpdateProjectCommandValidator(DbContext dbContext) {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id)
            .MustFindProjectById(dbContext);
    }
}
```

Then your `MustFindProjectById` extension method would look something like this:

```
public static class MustFindProjectByIdExtensions {
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, int> MustFindProjectById<T>
        (this IRuleBuilder<T, int> ruleBuilder, DbContext dbContext) {
        return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new MustFindProjectById(dbContext));
    }
}
```

...and it is just a wrapper around a custom `PropertyValidator`:

```
internal class MustFindProjectById : PropertyValidator {
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    internal MustFindProjectById(DbContext dbContext) {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    protected override IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext) {
        var projectId = (int)context.PropertyValue;
        var entity = dbContext.Projects.Find(projectId);
        return entity != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dan that works to see if the object exists but I want to also Validate the existing object.

Comment: @StevenT.Cramer so, when applying a command, you want to run validation rules against the data that is already in the database, before the command is applied? Doesn't sound right to me so maybe I don't know enough about the problem.

Comment: Imagine you have ShipOrdertToCustomerCommand with OrderId and CustomerId.  So for this command to be valid the Customer with CustomerId must exist and have a valid shipping address.  Just an example.